# Extracting Tables in Python from a website

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I want to extract the table on this website: https://www.wikirating.com/list-of-countries-by-credit-rating/

When I try with this code, I only obtain the first two lines of the website? What do I wrong or how can I specify that I want to extract the table?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.wikirating.com/list-of-countries-by-credit-rating/'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
print(df)
df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

Comment: You might be better off using a package such as [LXML](https://lxml.de) or [beautiful soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) .  These are able to parse the html on the page which makes it easier to extract what you are interested in.  Recommend doing some tutorial examples on these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `BeautifulSoup`. Here's something to get you started:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.wikirating.com/list-of-countries-by-credit-rating/'
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Find all tables on the page
tables = soup.find_all('table')

# Loop through each table
for table in tables:
    # Find all rows in the table
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    # Loop through each row and print the first three elements
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        # grabs the first four elements of the row and reads them
        if len(cells) >= 4:
            print(cells[0].text, cells[1].text, cells[2].text, cells[3].text)
```